# unexpected data offset flag 137 when restoring database using pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore a large database (14G) that was backed up using pg_dump.
I'm using this command to restore it.

`pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U username -d dbname backupfile.dump`

I have tried several other commands (using `pg_restore`) but I got the same error message.

Here is the error message:
`pg_restore: error: unexpected data offset flag 137`

Has anyone have any idea what was wrong? I haven't been able to find the meaning of the flag 137 ont the internet.

Note: I downloaded the database from server using `scp`, I'm quite sure the file has been downloaded completely. The database was backed up using pg_dump with postgresql version 13 (ubuntu), and I'm trying to restore it in my local (macOS) using posgresql 14. Could it be the postgresql version? I haven't encountered such problem before.

Comment: The dump is corrupted. How exactly was it created, what was the version of the database, and what was the version of `pg_dump`?

Comment: this is the output using pg_dump --version `pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 13.8 (Ubuntu 13.8-1.pgdg18.04+1)` 

I wonder if that was the case, I will try to download it again (or make new backup again), then see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, just as Laurenz said, the the dump file was corrupted. The disk space was full when the pg_dump was performed. I think it might be a good idea to have some kind of rollback process when the pg_dump encounters problems.